# Unable to apply skip, limit and order clauses in Neo4j using rest cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 2.1.5 using dependency `neo4j-rest-graphdb:2.0.1` in Grails and I query my DB using

`RestAPI restapi = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
RestCypherQueryEngine rcqer=new RestCypherQueryEngine(restapi)`

I created a parameter list

`Map<String, String> paramVal = new HashMap<>(); paramVal.put('limit', 10); paramVal.put('skip', 0); paramVal.put('order', 'name');`

My query looks like this

`String query = "match (c:MyLabel) return id(c) as Id, c.name as name skip ${param}.skip limit ${param}.limit;`

Execute the query like this

`result = rcqer.query(query,org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil.map("param",paramVal))"`

This shows error `Invalid input '.': expected whitespace, Limit, LOAD CSV,.....`
However works perfect when the parameters are used only in `where` clause.
Also the result is not in order while using only for `order by` clause, and works without any error.

Please let me know what is missing or if there is a limitation there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that particular part of the library but I would expect that you do not need to reference `param` directly as that is what the `{}` syntax is for (no dollar), this would make your query:

```
String query = "match (c:MyLabel) return id(c) as Id, c.name as name skip {skip} limit {limit}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, the query uses parameter as expected, it works for conditions like `where c.name = {param}.name`, however gives error for `skip` and `limit`